# Removing the frame from the Boxplot() function in R

Tags: r, boxplot

Does someone know how to remove the frame when producing a boxplot with the R `boxplot()` function?

With the `plot()` function there is an optinal argument, `frame=F`, that does the job... but it is not included in the `boxplot()` function...

Thank you very much!

Comment: So copy the code to your own local `marcoBoxplot()` and change it accordingly.

Comment: @Dirk For once we can't say to RTFM, because the use of `frame` is not even mentioned in that FM...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the option `frame=F` (or `frame.plot=F`) in the boxplot function :

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray",frame=F)
```

Other parameters that can be used in the boxplot function are (rather inconveniently) listed on the helppage of `?bxp`, which is the underlying function of `boxplot()`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `bty` in `par`. Using an example from the `boxplot` help:

```
par(bty='n')
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
```

Comment: @Marco : Why don't you just use the parameter frame (See Chases and my answer)? If you don't know what you're doing, you'll get serious problems when messing with par(), as it sets general parameters, not for the specific plot.

Comment: @Joris Meys: Yes you are right, I should use the parameter frame. Thx

Comment: One of the advantages of par and bty, however, is the ability to not only remove the frame but also to select which sides of the frame to remove.

par(bty='l'), for example, will remove only the top and right portions of the frame, which I believe makes for a much nicer boxplot than either par(bty='n') or frame=false.

Answer (score 4):

`boxplot()` seems to accept the `frame` argument just fine.

```
 boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
 #vs    
 boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray", frame = FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right :-S I do not know why I did not manage to make it work before... I am sorry for that stupid post!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest solution. Just set axes = 0

```html
boxplot(runif(100), axes = 0)
```